# How to tell a Registry Object how to create objects in PHP efficiently?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm creating an object registry to easily retrieve objects and handle global objects ( objects of which i need just one instance like wrappers around wp_functions or factories ) 
Basically i have various scenarioes to handle.

1) the object i need to create is a simple class.
2) the object i need to create is a simple class but there is no need for different instances.
3) the object i need to create is created by a factory.
4) the object i need to created needs some parameters.

This is the code i have

```
<?php

/**
 * @author nicola
 *
 */
class Ai1ec_Object_Registry implements Ai1ec_Registry_Interface {

    CONST PREFIX = 'Ai1ec_';

    static private $_objects = array();

    static private $_classes = array();

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     *
     * @see Ai1ec_Registry_Interface::get()
     *
     */
    public function get( $key ) {
        $classname = $this->get_classname();
        if( ! isset ( self::$_classes[$classname] ) ) {
            throw new Ai1ec_Registry_Exception( 
                'The class "' . $classname . '" was not registered'
            );
        }

        $options = self::$_classes[$classname];
        // if it's a global object and it's already set, return it
        if ( isset( $options['global'] ) && 
                isset( self::$_objects[$classname] ) ) {
            return self::$_objects[$classname];
        }
        $params = array();
        if( func_num_args() > 1 ) {
            $params = func_get_arg( 1 );
        }
        // check if the object needs a factory
        if ( isset( $options['factory'] ) ) {

            return $this->dispatch( 
                $options['factory'][0],
                $options['factory'][1],
                $params
            );
        } else {
            if ( empty( $params ) ) {
                return new $classname();
            } else {
                $class = new ReflectionClass( $classname );
                return $class->newInstanceArgs( $params );
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     *
     * @see Ai1ec_Registry_Interface::set()
     *
     */
    public function set( $key, $val ) {
        if ( ! is_object( $val ) ) {
            throw new Ai1ec_Registry_Exception( 'Only Objects can be stored in the registry' );
        }
        $classname = $this->get_classname();
        if ( isset( self::$_objects[$classname] ) ) {
            throw new Ai1ec_Registry_Exception( 'Only one object for each key is allowed' );
        }
        self::$_objects[$classname] = $val;
    }

    /**
     * Register a class into the registry
     * 
     * @param string $class_name The name of the class to registr
     * @param array $options     An array of options about the class.
     */
    public function register( $class_name, array $options ) {
        if( isset( self::$_classes[$class_name] ) ) {
            throw new Ai1ec_Registry_Exception( 'A class can\'t be registered twice' );
        }
        self::$_classes[$class_name] = $options;
    }

    /**
     * A call_user_func_array alternative.
     * 
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $method
     * @param array $params
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function dispatch( $class, $method, $params = array() ) {
        // get an instance of the class
        $class = $this->get( $class );
        switch ( count( $params)  ) {
            case 0:
                return $class->{$method}();
            case 1:
                return $class->{$method}( $params[0] );
            case 2:
                return $class->{$method}( $params[0], $params[1] );
            case 3:
                return $class->{$method}( $params[0], $params[1], $params[2] );
            case 4:
                return $class->{$method}( 
                    $params[0], 
                    $params[1], 
                    $params[2],
                    $params[3]
                 );
            case 5:
                return $class->{$method}(
                    $params[0],
                    $params[1],
                    $params[2],
                    $params[3],
                    $params[4]
                );
            default:
                return call_user_func_array( array( $class, $method ), $params );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the class name from the key.
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    private function get_classname( $key ) {
        return self::PREFIX . $key;
    }
}
```

it should handle all the cases, but is this the best way to do this? Doesn't this introduce too much overhead?

Comment: It is not the best way. You should read about dependency injection, which already has plenty of implementations of containers that do exactly what you are trying to do, but with better ability to reuse code. As a starter, try to have a look at [Pimple](https://github.com/fabpot/Pimple).

Comment: You can also look at [Symphony Dependency Injection Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) and [Dice](http://r.je/dice.html#example1). [This one (Viocon)](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/viocon) is also fine, built by my beloved little brother ([Usman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/656489/usman)).